# Run unit tests inside web worker

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, web-worker

I would like to run Karma tests inside a web-worker. My reason is that some code could work fine in standard browser environment, but then fail when running in a web worker. Consider the line:

```
var result = window.Math.abs(-1);
```

This would work fine in usual browser code, because of the global `window` object, but it would fail if it was part of a web-worker, because it doesn't have a global `window` object  (unless `window` has been manually defined somewhere).

I realise I could just write `self.Math.abs(-1)`, or even just `Math.abs(-1)`, but my aim is to get the test to catch such things.

How can Karma run the tests inside of a web-worker?